# Unable to use overloaded [] operator on an object using the this pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I'm having issues with the overloaded + operator and the overloaded [] operator. The [] function works fine when used on the OrderedList right object but I cannot get it to return the correct value when used with the this pointer.

The way the code works in main is something like:
    list3 = list1 + list2

where list2 becomes 'right' in the parameter list, and I am trying to use the this pointer to get the value at the subscript for list1.

The error I'm getting is "cannot convert OrderedList to double in assignment" but I am unsure why it is trying to assign an OrderedList?

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

```
OrderedList OrderedList::operator+(OrderedList &right)
{
    int size1 = this -> _size;
    int size2 = right.getSize();
    double x, y;
    y = right[size2];
    x = this[size1];
    OrderedList list3;
    return list3;
}

double OrderedList::operator[](int subscript) const // returns rvalue 
{
    int x = OrderedList::_size;
    if (subscript > x)
    {
        cout << "Error: number is bigger than the size of the list" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temporary = OrderedList::getListHead();
        for (int counter = 1; counter < subscript; counter++)
        {
            temporary = temporary -> next;
        }
        double nodeValue = temporary -> item;
        return nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: "cannot convert OrderedList to double in assignment" where is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a pointer so why you try to do `this[size1]` it is doing pointer arithmetic. Think:

```
int a[] = {0, 1};
int *b[2] = &a;
```

To get to the actual data from `b` we must derefence it first:

```
int c = (*b)[1];
```

Likewise here we must dereference `this`:

```
x = (*this)[size1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try to dereference the pointer but I was still typing it incorrectly, I was writing something like *this[size1] and not using the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`this->operator[](/*your parameters here*/)` will work.

You can drop `this->` although it can make things less clear.

(`this[size1]` will perform some nasty pointer arithmetic - equivalent to `this + size1`: therefore almost certainly accessing memory you don't own).

Comment: @clcto: Yes I dare say it would. And much clearer ;-) Put as an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did try to dereference the pointer but must not have been typing that correctly either.